# Setting the Default User in SQL Server 2008 is Inconsistent Across Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 databases a production database and a QA database. I am attempting to promote code from QA to production and used Visual Studio 2012 SQL Schema Compare. I noticed that my production database table has a default constraint in the UpdatedBy column like this:

```
(upper(right(suser_sname(),6)))
```

But my QA database table has the same default constraint on the same column UpdatedBy set to this:

```
(upper(right(suser_sname(),(6))))
```

This is causing my SQL Schema compare to report these columns as different and needing to be changed. No matter what I do I can't get my QA table to add the constraint as (upper(right(suser_sname(),6))) like prodcution, it always defines it as:

```
(upper(right(suser_sname(),(6))))
```

Am I missing something. I know that they both return the correct 6 character user id, it's just that the compare reports it as different.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using SSMS to add the constraint in the QA database, have you tried adding it manually in a script with the exact format of the constraint in the production database instead?

Comment: At vs2012 you can choose to ignore that table/column and keep going with your diff. Also why bother? If you let that go how much damage it ill do?